# Injected views remain null for inflated layouts

Tags: android-layout, layout-inflater, roboguice

Can I use Roboguice @InjectView on elements that are included in a layout that will be inflated? It seems right to me that the elements are declaired @Nullable at first, as they are not known until the inflate is done. But after inflate, the elements still remain null until a "findViewById" is done.

As an example:
I use the following code to inject a nullable textview (the title) that is included in title_layout that will be inflated in the main layout:

```
@Nullable @InjectView(R.id.title) TextView title;
@InjectView(R.id.title_info) LinearLayout titleContainer;
```

And then in onCreate() method I do this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
inflater.inflate(R.layout.title_layout, titleContainer);
```

And I have the **main.xml**:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/title_info">
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayot>
```

and **title_layout.xml**:

```
  <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TextView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/title" 
      android:text="my title" />
</LinearLayot>
```

The title (TextView) from the inflated view is always **null**, even after the title_layout is inflated.

Doing this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
inflater.inflate(R.layout.title_layout, titleContainer);
title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);\
```

solves the problem.

Is there any way to use @InjectView?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem - turns out I was extending `Activity` instead of `RoboActivity`, so it was never handling the injection.